# Chart.js custom spanGaps

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to make the chart.js plugin a little more custom. I need to have 2 variables that when used can populate the spanGaps / breaks in the chart with a solid fill color and text in the break point. I am attaching a picture of what i need. I will include the code but it wont seem to work in codepen or other code editable sites. If you can i would be glad to work with it.

I cannot find in the documentation where i can create options to specify what these null data attributes would be.
[image: Picture of desired outcome]

```
<div class="assessment-chart" data-total-quarters="20" data-total-years="5" data-chart-width="3000" data-chart-height="240">
                            <canvas id="assessmentChart" width="3000" height="240"></canvas>
                          </div>



var assessmentChartconfig = {

    data: {
        labels: [["YEAR 1","Quarter 1"], ["YEAR 1","Quarter 2"], ["YEAR 1","Quarter 3"], ["YEAR 1","Quarter 4"], ["YEAR 2","Quarter 1"], ["YEAR 2","Quarter 2"], ["YEAR 2","Quarter 3"], ["YEAR 2","Quarter 4"], ["YEAR 3","Quarter 1"], ["YEAR 3","Quarter 2"], ["YEAR 3","Quarter 3"], ["YEAR 3","Quarter 4"], ["YEAR 4","Quarter 1"], ["YEAR 4","Quarter 2"], ["YEAR 4","Quarter 3"], ["YEAR 4","Quarter 4"], ["YEAR 5","Quarter 1"], ["YEAR 5","Quarter 2"], ["YEAR 5","Quarter 3"], ["YEAR 5","Quarter 4"]],
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: "Your Performance",
            fill: false,
            lineTension:0,
            spanGaps:false,
            yAxesGroup: "1",
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yourperformance,
            borderColor: window.chartColors.yourperformance,
            data: [
                64,
                75,
                70,
                null,
                72,
                75,
                80
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: "Community Comparison",
            fill: false,
            lineTension:0,
            spanGaps:false,
            yAxesGroup: "1",
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.communitycomparison,
            borderColor: window.chartColors.communitycomparison,
            data: [
                70,
                70,
                60,
                null,
                70,
                50,
                65
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend:{
            display:false,
            position:'bottom',
            labels: {
                boxWidth:15,
                defaultFontFamily: '"latobold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                defaultFontSize:14,
                defaultFontStyle:'bold'
            }
        },
        title:{
            display:false,
            text:''
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: false,
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                offsetGridLines: true
              },
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: false,
                    labelString: 'YEAR:Quarter'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: false,
                ticks: {
                    min:0,
                    max:100,
                    stepSize:20
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: '%'
                },
                afterUpdate:function(evt) {
                    assessmentChartResizeCallback(evt);
                }
            }]
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0
            }
        },
        responsive:false,
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
        onResize: function(evt) {
            assessmentChartResizeCallback(evt);
        }
    }
};

function assessmentChartResizeCallback(evt) {
    try{
        $('.assessment-chart-scroller').height(window.assessmentChart.canvas.height - 50);
        $('.y-axis-container').height(window.assessmentChart.canvas.height - 50);
    }catch(exc){}
}

function setupChartArrows() {
    $('.previous-arrow-container').click(function(){
        var currentPosition = Number($('.assessment-chart').css('left').replace('px',''));
        if(currentPosition < 0) {
            var newPosition = currentPosition;
            newPosition += Number( Number($('.assessment-chart').attr('data-chart-width')) / Number($('.assessment-chart').attr('data-total-quarters')));
            if(newPosition < 0){
                $('.assessment-chart').animate({'left': newPosition}, 500);
            }else if(currentPosition < 0){
                $('.assessment-chart').animate({'left': 0}, 500);
            }
        }
    });
    $('.next-arrow-container').click(function(){
        var currentPosition = Number($('.assessment-chart').css('left').replace('px',''));
        if(currentPosition <= 0) {
            var newPosition = currentPosition;
            newPosition -= Number(Number($('.assessment-chart').attr('data-chart-width')) / Number($('.assessment-chart').attr('data-total-quarters')));
            var maxPosition = Number($('.assessment-chart').attr('data-chart-width')) - Number($('.assessment-chart').attr('data-chart-width')) / Number($('.assessment-chart').attr('data-total-quarters'));
            if(newPosition <= 0 && newPosition >= maxPosition * -1){
                $('.assessment-chart').animate({'left': newPosition}, 500);
            }else{
                newPosition = maxPosition * -1;
                $('.assessment-chart').animate({'left': newPosition}, 500);
            }
        }
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("assessmentChart").getContext("2d");
    window.assessmentChart = new Chart(ctx, assessmentChartconfig);
    setupChartArrows();
};
```

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this problem ?

Comment: We figured out a workaround as we were not able to reach this exact solution. The client was happy enough !)

Comment: Hi @user2025730, it's be awesome to see your workaround. I'm trying to add a dashed line in the gap. many thanks

Comment: Apologies. This was so long ago and I no longer am working with this company. I will not be able to support this question. It was not easy from what I remember and the client ditched the want after we got it working as they requested. Waste of time for me. Hope you have better luck.